# Dylib can run without code sign in iOS?

Tags: ios, dynamic-linking

I learn from somewhere `dylib` should be signed in iOS, otherwise `dyld` will refuse to execute it.

But when I test the [example](https://github.com/ddeville/Dynamic-iOS) of [this post](http://ddeville.me/2014/04/dynamic-linking). The `dylib` is not signed by default in this project, but it just running well when try to open it. I have verified the `dylib`'s binary doesn't contain `lc_code_signature`.

Anyone can explain this?

---

I test on a jailbreak device with 3 cases for a `dylib` without `lc_code_signature`.

1. Dynamic linked with the binary, so the `dylib` is list in `LOAD COMMAND`.
2. Copy to the main bundle, and `dlopen` it.
3. Copy to the `Document` dir and open it.

They all succeed.

Comment: well, jailbreaks usually disable signature checking completely so no wonder it works.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: The below applies only to non-jailbroken devices. Jailbreaks usually disable signature checking completely to allow unsigned homebrew software to run.

---

Apparently only libraries which are listed as dependencies of the executable in the header (`LC_LOAD_DYLIB` and similar commands) are checked, and those loaded with `dlopen` are not.

This is mentioned indirectly in the [Code Signing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html):

> As with other Gatekeeper functions, this check is performed the first
>   time the app is run. It does not apply to libraries that the app loads
>   itself using the `dlopen` function, although those libraries are still
>   potentially subject to library validation, as described in Using
>   Library Validation.

Following the link, we see this passage:

> Starting in iOS 8 and macOS 10.10, the system offers library
>   validation as a policy for the dynamic libraries that a process links
>   against.
>
> The policy is simple: A program may link against any library
>   with the same team identifier in its code signature as the main
>   executable, or with any Apple system library. Requests to link against
>   other libraries are denied.
>
> In iOS, an Apple system library is a
>   library that Apple mastered into the OS image. In macOS, an Apple
>   system library is a library shipped in /System/Library. The team
>   identifier is the 10-character alphanumeric string, such as
>   YH9SZ5LKR4, associated with your developer account, and recorded in
>   your Apple-issued signing certificate. 
>   In iOS, library validation is
>   **always enabled** for all apps. There is nothing you need to do to opt
>   in.

So it would seem that `dlopen` *should not* be able to load unsigned libraries in iOS 8 and higher, though I have not checked this.

Comment: Thanks for you detail explain. I use iOS9 to test, and still can load unsigned binary.

Comment: @Karl: and you're not using a jailbroken device? In that case it seems either the doc is wrong, or there is a bug.